# Neural Network to Interpolate Matrices

Tags: neural-networks

I am considering some possibilities to improve a Variable Gain nonlinear control system.

One of the drawbacks of the current technique is that the change of the gains is discrete and the switching effect is highly undesirable...

The gain matrices are 4x16 and are calculated for some values of a bounded variable and then selected trough a lookup table.

So, what my idea was to try and do this with an Neural Network, that would receive as input the control variable and give the gain matrix as output, allowing my control to be continuous or almost continuous.

Is this idea possible/feasible?

My knowledge on neural nets is very poor, so I hope you can enlighten me somehow.

Comment: Welcome to AI!  (I took the liberty of editing your tags, as "[control problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI_control_problem)" has a slightly different meaning than I think you intended;)